# py.test can't import Pandas "TypeError: __name__ must be set to a string object"

Tags: python, pytest

[EDIT]
The minimal example for this problem is to import sure before pandas. Sure is a testing library that allows tests like (1).should.equal(2). The problem I have is that if I import sure from multiple test files, it gives the same error when I run my tests.

This code

```
 import sure
 import pandas as pd
```

Results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\lggodin\Documents\projects\vrops\dataapi\py27env\lib\site-packages\pandas\__in
it__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 761, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:108072)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 724, in pandas.tslib._make_error_func (pandas\tslib.c:16177)
TypeError: __name__ must be set to a string object
(py27env)
```

python 2.7.11 on Windows 8.

I am using py.test to test a script that uses Pandas. If I run py.test tests/unit/test_environment.py the tests run successfully. If I just run py.test or py.test tests/unit it fails with "TypeError: **name** must be set to a string object"

My test file imports environment.py which imports pandas, and pandas imports tslib. This is where it is failing. Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I am using python 2.7 in a virtualenv. All my main code works. It is just the test file that fails. 
Thanks in advance. I pasted my directory structure and an example of the unsuccessful py.test command.

```
$ py.test tests/unit
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.11, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: C:\Users\lggodin\Documents\projects\vrops\dataapi\dataapi\tests\unit, inifile:
collected 8 items / 1 errors

tests\unit\test_client.py .........
tests\unit\test_propertymapper.py ...............

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________________________ test_environment.py _____________________________
tests\unit\test_environment.py:1: in <module>
    from dataapi.dataapi.environment import Environment
dataapi\environment.py:1: in <module>
    import pandas as pd
..\py27env\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:25: in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
pandas/tslib.pyx:761: in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:108072)
    ???
pandas/tslib.pyx:724: in pandas.tslib._make_error_func (pandas\tslib.c:16177)
    ???
E   TypeError: __name__ must be set to a string object
===================== 24 passed, 1 error in 1.07 seconds ======================
(py27env)
.
├── __init__.py
├── cert
│   └── intel.pem
├── console_setup.py
├── dataapi
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── client.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── environment.py
│   ├── propertymapper.py
│   ├── resource.py
│   └── resourceproperty.py
├── temp
│   └── certified_vm_properties.json
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── integration
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── test_resource.py
│   │   └── test_resourceproperties.py
│   └── unit
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── test_client.py
│       ├── test_environment.py
│       └── test_propertymapper.py
├── Untitled.ipynb
├── vm_properties.json
└── vrops_api_testing.ipynb
```

Comment: Please post a small amount of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I spent an hour trying to reproduce this, but I can't. I even copied my original test_environment.py and environment.py into a similar directory structure and everything works.  The good news is that resolved the issue for me. The bad news is that I don't know why.

Comment: Well, I thought I had it, but I didn't. Here is the problem.
I use the sure library for testing. This allows me to write tests like (1).should.equal(1)   If more than one file imports sure, I get this error. Sure monkeypatches all objects and I assume that is the root of the problem. The workaround is only to import sure in one of the test files, or not use sure to test classes that use Pandas.  Interesting problem.